# ASP .NET REST API and WEBSITE in one view

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, webview, webforms

I have standard asp form app that should be able to do two things - behave just like a normal website but also be able to respond to REST api calls. For example my Web View called Login.aspx should be able to render out login fields but if it is called from my phone (using params for example ?mobile=true) then it should return a JSON.

I am currently using function

```
void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(context.Request["mobile"]))
        {

        }else{....}
```

The problem is that this only works if param mobile is supplied. If I try to render a web view it is empty. How do I render out elements I have in the web view?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of looking for a parameter to identify a mobile device, you can try one of two options -- the first and simplest, if it works for you, is:

```
Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice()
```

If that works for you, then you can go forwards with it -- if not, though (I've seen some cases of people having issues with it) then try instead writing a little function to parse against:

```
Request.UserAgent
```

In that case, you'll want to compare the string value to possible string values of mobile browsers (which can change over time, of course, so you'd need to keep it updated, and where possible use partial matches against common words, like "iphone" or "blackberry").  But either solution is very simple, and should work as an effective option in place of your passed parameter.